# How does this isPrime function work?

Tags: c, primes

I was reading http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~weber/slipOff/hashmap_c.html and having hard time understanding how this function works:

```
static unsigned long isPrime(unsigned long val)
{
  int i, p, exp, a;

  for (i = 9; i--;)
  {
    a = (rand() % (val-4)) + 2;
    p = 1;
    exp = val-1;
    while (exp)
    {
      if (exp & 1)
        p = (p*a)%val;

      a = (a*a)%val;
      exp >>= 1;
    }

    if (p != 1)
      return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

If its name is any indicator of what it does, it checks whether a number is prime. However, I can't figure out how it does that.

I can understand what each statement do, but I don't see how it works.

Comment: Run in a debugger, and call for a small prime, and then step through the code line by line while looking at how all variables changes and what they change to.

Comment: @yasar its based on little fermat theorem

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically if a number `q` is prime then fermat theorem states that

`a`<sup>`(q - 1)`</sup> = `1 (mod q)`

where `a` and `q` are co-prime.

So basically the `while` loop is just calculating the some random number to the power `val-1` and also taking the modulo `val`. If the end result is 1, it says `val` is prime otherwise not. But in general this can be true for some random value of `a` even if `p` is not prime. Thus we generally take a few random numbers and repeat the same procedure, if all give `p=1` in the end we say that `val` is prime with high probability ( the outer loop is for repeating the procedure , more iterations more is the probability that your answer is correct). So basically if `val` is prime this method will correctly detect it as prime but if it is composite it might detect is as prime, with probability of that being low. Although this method is not as effective as other methods.

Comment: Then the function name may be a misnomer. [Probable prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime) is more correct